# DNS is not resolving with A record for ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elb, aws-route53

We have Elastic Load Balancer in AWS that has one instance as webserver in the Target group.

We are able to resolve the domain/application URL with the ELB DNS however created A-Record in hosted zone in route 53 not able to resolve to webserver.

```
ELB URL ABC-XXXX-alb-1583984639.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com  --> Able to resolve it properly
```

Route 53 A-Record entry:

```
XYZ.example.com A ABC-XXXX-alb-1583984639.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

(above A-Record is pointing to ELB url which is not resolving)

I changed the record type as CNAME still same issue.

I recreated the A-Record entry but no luck.

Certificate and domain is valid.

Comment: What errors do you get?